# Merged local changes to master branch, then undid some of those changes in the master branch, now I can't commit the changes from my local branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am very new to git, so bear with me:

I wanted to merge changes from my local branch to my master branch. I merged all my changes, then committed the ones I needed to in the master branch, then "undid" all of my uncommitted changes in the master branch (in Visual Studio) in order to keep it clean, because these changes were not ready yet. If I now go back into my local branch, these changes doesn't show up as ready to commit or anything, I don't know how to get them back to the master branch (which I will need to in the future).

TL;DR: I have a local branch that is different from the master branch, but the changes doesn't show up when i want to commit.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the git commands and Visual Studio actions you did? For example, I don't understand "I merged all my changes, then committed the ones I needed to in the master branch, then "undid" all of my uncommitted changes in the master branch". "merge" has a very specific meaning in git, and if you did that then there wouldn't be any changes for you to commit or not commit

Comment: Of course. I didn't use command line for any of this, but Visual Studio GUI actions.First I made changes to my local branch, and then committed this. Then I merged this commit to my master branch. After this, while working in the master branch, I committed some of these changes and pushed them. After this, I pressed "undo" on the remaining changes that were not committed nor pushed in the master branch. Now I have one local branch that has changes, and one master branch that does no longer have these changes. But, if I try to merge local into master, there are apparently no changes.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow. To use an example, in `local` you wrote the code `var a = 1` and committed that. Then merged it to `master`. After that you changed it to `var a = 2` AND wrote `var b = 1`. Then you committed `var a = 2` to master, and undid `var b = 1`. So now `local` has `var a = 1` and `master` has `var a = 2`.
Does that (more or less) describe the situation you're facing?
Also, you mention you're new to git - are you familiar with any other source control system?

Comment: More like this: I wrote the code `var a = 1` in one file, and `var b = 2` in another file, both in my `local` branch. Then I committed both of these and merged it to `master`. After that I committed ONLY the `var a = 1` file and pushed it in the `master` branch. The `var b = 2` file, I pressed `Undo` for, because I didn't want those changes in my `master` branch, only in my `local` branch. So now I have `var a = 1` and `var b = 2` in my `local` branch, but only `var a = 1` in my `master` branch. And I can't commit or push or merge `var b = 2` from my `local` branch to my `master` branch.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the issue. Can you run `git log` in the `master` branch and describe the output? This will list the commit from most recent to oldest. So, you should see the messages matching up to what you entered in the "commit message" area from Visual Studio